# Is the work licensed with Apache license version 2.0 is free to use?

Tags: android

Hai I am working with an Android app and I included some external libraries licensed under Apache license version 2.0.can I use those libraries in my app without any restrictions ?

Comment: Maybe this helps. https://choosealicense.com

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about legal issues, not coding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache License 2.0 is a permissive license whose main conditions require preservation of copyright and license notices. Contributors provide an express grant of patent rights. Licensed works, modifications, and larger works may be distributed under different terms and without source code.

Permissions:

- Commercial Use: The software & derivatives can be used for commercial purposes.
- Distribution: You can distribute the software.
- Modification: The software can be modified.
- Patent Use: The license provides an express grant of patent rights from the contributor to the recipient.
- Private Use: You can modify and use the software without distributing it.

Conditions:

- License and Copyright Notice: Include a copy of the license & copyright notice with the software.
- State Changes: Indicate changes made to the code.

Limitations:

- Liability: The license includes a limitation of liability.
- Trademark Use: The license explicitly states that it does not grant you trademark rights, even though licenses without such a statement probably do not grant you any implicit trademark rights.
- Warranty: The license explicitly states that it does not provide any warranty.